# emacs-nox doesn't load the files I ask it to at command line

Tags: configuration, emacs

I have a few different Ubuntu installs and this is the first time I've experienced this.

I have `emacs-nox` installed, because I hate graphical versions of emacs.  Normally when I type `emacs test.txt` it will load `test.txt` if it exists and load a blank file if it does not exist.

Instead, on this machine, it says:

```
File exists: /home/myusername/.emacs.d/
```

And loads a blank file, even if it exists.  Then when I try to save it, it makes me specify a full path, like I had not told it where I wanted it to save when I called it from the command line.

Any thoughts on what might be causing this?  I didn't customize my emacs install in any way, and I've tried removing and re-installing the package to no avail.

**Edit to add requested details**

```
user@comp:~$ ls -l ~/.emacs.d
ls: cannot open directory /home/user/.emacs.d: Permission denied
user@comp:~$ sudo ls -l ~/.emacs.d
total 0
```

Comment: migrated to unix.SE at OP request.

Comment: List the files in `.emacs.d/` and paste the contents of any emacs configuration files.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman That did it.  I looked at the output above, deleted the non-existent but locked-down directory, and now it works.  Care to make your comment an answer and I'll mark it as answered?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comment by @EvanTeitelman ,  I looked at the output in the question's edit, deleted the non-existent but locked-down directory `~/.emacs.d`, and now it works.

```
sudo rm -r ~/.emacs.d
```

This appears to be a common thing, at least on Xubuntu.  I noticed another installation doing it today.  So hopefully this will help someone.